# Grouping Query Reselts In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible in Google Sheets to group the query results based on the order column?
The result will be similar to what is found in Google Tablets or Notion, and by using conditional formatting, more clarification can be added so that the results are easier to read.

What I want is an arrangement like this:
[image: Image from Google Tablets]

[image: Image from Google Sheets]

Here is a link to an example sheet:
[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15yrWhInGEALsIY6iHVghQiz0YOVUn78CPtP71NEOz5s/edit?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15yrWhInGEALsIY6iHVghQiz0YOVUn78CPtP71NEOz5s/edit#gid=547577871) you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),sort(unique(tocol(filter(Flights!A2:G,Flights!A1:G1=B2),1))),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,c,filter(Flights!A:G,choosecols(Flights!A:G,xmatch(B2,Flights!A1:G1))=c)))))
```

[image]